# How to pass a parameter value into a JDBC repository @Query

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to use a Lookup strategy of JDBC repository:

```
@Query("select * from USERS where USERNAME = :id")
User findById(@Param("id") UserId id);
```

As you can see an `id` parameter has the custom type `UserId`. How can I convert it to a simple String? Should I register some converter? Where and how?

I also tried the next queries `... where USERNAME = :id.value`, `... where USERNAME = :#{id.value}` but they doesn't work.

**UPD**

This is my Spring Boot configuration:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories
public class PersistenceConfig extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed a Spring source code and found that for such cases they used `@WritingConverter`s (before I thought about `@ReadingConverter`s, that's why i didn't get success) which can be registered in usual way through `JdbcConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories
public class PersistenceConfig extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public JdbcCustomConversions jdbcCustomConversions() {
        return new JdbcCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(
                new UserIdToStringConverter()));
    }
}
```

where `UserIdToStringConverter` has the next implementation:

```
@WritingConverter
public class UserIdToStringConverter implements Converter<UserId, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(UserId source) {
        return (String) source.value();
    }
}
```

**UPD**

I also found that `ConditionalGenericConverter` doesn't work. For conditional converters the method `getConvertibleTypes()` must return `null` (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/GenericConverter.html#getConvertibleTypes--)). but when I do so a `matches` method is not called. Look's like Spring bug (spring-data-jdbc-2.0.4.RELEASE).

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```java
@Query("select * from USERS where USERNAME = :#{#id.value}")
User findById(@Param("id") UserId id);
```

Read more at https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions

Comment: As I understand, JPA `@Query` is not the same as JDBC one. So, this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it's not JDBC query - it's JPQL query by default (unless you use `Query`'s argument `nativeQuery = true`)

Comment: But I need a solution for `org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query` -not for `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`.